# cmd.executeNonQuery() Update

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access

I have a program where a user can update their Password by Entering their old password in a textbox, and entering their new password in a separate textbox.

An update query then updates the database with the new password.

```
Try
            If tbOldPassword.Text <> "" Then
                For Each Row In ds.Tables("sqlAddNewDetails").Rows
                    If Row.Item(0) = gblstrUserID Then
                        If Row.Item(1) = tbOldPassword.Text Then
                            If tbPassword.Text = tbRePassword.Text Then

                                'Updates the database
                                sqlUpdate = ("UPDATE Users SET Password = '" & tbPassword.Text & "' WHERE userID = " & Row.Item(0))
                                Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlUpdate, con)
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                                MsgBox("Password successfully changed")
                            Else : MsgBox("The passwords are not the same")
                            End If
                        Else : MsgBox("Invalid old password")
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

However, everytime the code gets to cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), it throws up an error saying that there is a syntax error in the Update query. However, If I use this query in Microsoft Access, it works fine so the Update query itself is written correctly. What could be wrong?

Note: I am using an UPDATE query in another piece of code within the same Sub routine and it works there. Its something about this query.

Note Again: If I change the Update query to UPDATE Users SET EMAIL = '" & tbPassword.Text & "' WHERE userID = " & Row.Item(0)" it works. Something about Password that throws that error.

Comment: What error message you have ?

Comment: Syntax Error in UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Password is a keyword, so wrap it in square brackets as below,

`UPDATE Users SET [Password] =.....`

Comment: +1 This is the right answer. However, that code is a bit inefficient. (No exit for...). Not to mention if the password contains a single quote...

Comment: Perfect. I had a suspicion this would be the problem but didn't really think it through. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I must see the error msg, until that i notice 2 things :

1 - con.Open() not exists !!!, it might be not opend
2 - In the query if UserId is a number so the query string should be :
         `"' WHERE userID = " & CStr(Row.Item(0))`

if UserID is a string the query string should be :
         `"' WHERE userID = '" & Row.Item(0) & "'"`

Comment: I stated the error in the comment above. I do have con.Open() but I did not post it. UserID is Autonumber so that isn't the problem. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Ok then Convert Row.Item(0) to string ....CStr(Row.Item(0)), because you can't attach a string to a int

Answer (score 1):

I would probably check to see what the sqlUpdate variable contains before the execute occurs. It's likely that it doesn't contain what you think it does. I'd copy the string value and paste it into SQL Server Management Studio and try running it directly to verify it.

Having said that, I **really** wouldn't write this code using string concatenation. You're opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks. What would happen if a user has a single quote in their password? Use a SQL parameter instead, something like this:

```
sqlUpdate = "UPDATE Users SET Password = ? WHERE userID = ?"
cmd.Parameters.Add(tbPassword.Text)
cmd.Parameters.Add(Row.Item(0))
```

Hmm...I'd also probably not use OleDb either. I'd use the native client.

Of course, I have to link to the classic [XKCD Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: It very difficult indeed to get SQL injection to work with MS Access. Access will only allow one statement to be executed, so all the usual methods just won't work. I can understand that SQL injection needs to be advertised, but it will only be relevant if the OP changes the database.

Comment: Not really. Just because you're limited to one statement doesn't mean there aren't a whole lot of other attacks available. For example, if they're doing this for updating the password, I'm sure the login code looks very similar: SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userID = 1 AND [Password] = xxx. It becomes really easy to inject something like: ' OR 1=1 as the password. Now you can login without a password. And more than likely the first account w/be an admin account. It's so easy to avoid this with parameters it almost never makes sense to NOT use them.